# Formatting date, ordinal suffix for the day of the month

Tags: php, date

So if I use:

```
<?php echo date_format($date, "j M Y") ?>
```

I get a date in the following format: 5 Jan 1950.

However, what I want is something along the lines of: 5th Jan 1950

How would I go about adding the extra th?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Look at the formats here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php, but

```
<?php echo date_format($date, "jS M Y") ?><br>
```

For international dates, I guess you would do something like:

```
$ordinal = new NumberFormatter($locale, NumberFormatter::ORDINAL);
$ordinal = $ordinal->format(date_format($date, "j"));
$pattern = "d'{$ordinal}' MMM yyyy";
$dateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter($locale, IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL, $timezone, IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN);
$dateFormatter->setPattern($pattern);
$dateFormatter->format($date->getTimestamp());
```

The above is untested but it seems like it would work.

Comment: S relates to "English ordinal suffix for the day of the month". what about output in other languages ?

Comment: IntlDateFormatter works great, except for the ordinal suffix : there is nothing similar to the "S" from date_format : http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classSimpleDateFormat.html#details

Comment: In a localized date, the ordinal suffix isn't always needed. NumberFormatter provides the suffix for any number, but doesn't know when the suffix it is needed.

Answer (score 8):

```
echo date_format($date, "jS M Y");
```

Just check the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: You just forgot 95% of people on the planet have "not English" as their native language.